# Mysql record count from related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get a records count from related tables. I am able to achieve the result I need by breaking the queries and merging the arrays but I know it's inefficient.

I am looking for a cleaner and efficient way of doing this. 
All tables are one-to-many. Example:
-One User has many Objects
-One Object has many Items

```
Table Users
 ______________
| ID   |  UID  |
 ______________
|  1   |  U1   |
|  2   |  U2   |
 ______________
```

```
Table Objects
 ______________
| ObjID | UID  |
 ______________
|  o1   |  U1  |
|  o2   |  U1  |
|  o3   |  U1  |  
 ______________
```

```
Table Items
 _________________
| itemID |  ObjID |
 _________________
|  i1    |  o1    |
|  i2    |  o1    |
|  i3    |  o1    |
|  i4    |  o1    |
|  i5    |  o1    |
|  i6    |  o2    |
 _________________
```

The result I am looking for for U1 is:

```
| Objects |  Items  |
|   3     |    6    |
```

This sql is where I got stuck:

```
    select count(objects.id), count(items.id)
    from users
    left join Objects on objects.uid = users.uid
    left join Items on items.objID = objects.objID 
    where users.uid = 'U1'
```

Comment: I m trying to edit the question as a copy/paste messed it up but not sure how. edit: done

Comment: Essentially you want to count all of one thing, and distinct occurrences of another thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
create table users
(user_id serial primary key,name char(2) unique
);

insert into users values (101,'U1'),(102,'U2');

create table user_objects
(user_id int not null
,object_id int not null
,primary key(user_id,object_id)
);

insert into user_objects values
(101,1),
(101,2),
(101,3);

create table object_items
(object_id int not null
,item_id int not null
,primary key(object_id,item_id)
);

insert into object_items values
(1,1001),
(1,1002),
(1,1003),
(1,1004),
(1,1005),
(2,1001);

select u.name
     , count(distinct uo.object_id) objects
     , count(oi.item_id) items
  from users u
  left
  join user_objects uo 
    on uo.user_id = u.user_id
  left 
  join object_items oi
    on oi.object_id = uo.object_id
group
    by u.user_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2285/1

Comment: So I was one "distinct" away from the solution : )
Could you help me understand why you didnt think that "distinct" on "oi.item_id" was necessary as @nick put it?

Comment: Well, You related the tables on uid , which was not the primary key. And I found your table/column naming policy inconsistent and confusing ;-)

Comment: As for DISTINCT, (object_id,item_id) is unique, so DISTINCT must be redundant.

Comment: UID is the primary key but that's another story ;-P
Thought so about the distinct just wanted to make sure.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that because object_items are 'user agnostic', GB's idea of using a subquery to count items per object may be more efficient - worth exploring anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to get the desired result is to use correlated subqueries:

```
select (select count(*) 
        from Objects 
        where UID = 'U1') as Objects,
       (select count(*)
        from Items as i
        inner join Objects as o on i.ObjID = o.ObjID
        where o.UID = 'U1') as Items
```

Another way is to create a derived table of items per object and join to this table to get the total items per user:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Objects, SUM(cnt_per_oID) AS Items
FROM Users AS u
JOIN Objects AS o ON u.UID = o.UID
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT ObjID, COUNT(*) cnt_per_oID
   FROM Items
   GROUP BY ObjID
) AS i ON o.ObjID = i.ObjID
WHERE u.UID = 'U1'
GROUP BY u.UID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45146/4)

Comment: The double reference to u1 is a bit icky though

Answer (score 0):

Try this: though i am not sure about your item count

```
select count(objects.id), count(distinct items.id)
 from Items inner join Objects on objects.ObjID= users.ObjID
 inner join Items on users.uid= objects.uid
 where users.uid = 'U1'
```

Comment: Users table doesnt have a ObjID

Comment: but it has userid and object table also has userid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(distinct ObjId) Objects,
       count(distinct ItemId) Items
from Items i
where exists(select 1 from Objects
             where ObjId = i.ObjId and UID = 'U1');
```